# Work with encrypted data storage in TestComplete 9

Tags: testcomplete8

> The script below demonstrates how to work with encrypted data storage.
>   Encrypted information is stored in the SecureStringStorage.dat file
>   that is located in the project suite folder. The algoritm of encoding
>   and decoding is implemented in the SecureStringStorage script
>   extension that you can download below.

http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/9030/

Does this extension exist for TestComplete 9? Or is there any similar extension? I want to crypt the password in my .ini-file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just checked the script extension and the JScript example in TestComplete 9.0 - they work correctly.

The script extensions format for TestComplete 9 is exactly the same as that of TestComplete 8, so things were expected to work.

For data encrypting, the script extension's code uses the .NET Framework functions, which means that the code is expected to work in any version of TestComplete.

So, everything indicates that the results of my testing are quite expected - you can use the script extension in TestComplete 9. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is the first time I installed a Script Extension and since the link was broken that explained how to do it I had no idea on how to do that. Thank you for updating the page, I assume you did it :)

Comment: Yep, we updated the page :)

Comment: How do I install the extension to TestComplete version 8, if 9 is already installed and thus tcx opens with TestComplete 9? I need both versions.

Comment: You can just put the extension file (tcx) to the "<TestComplete 8>\Bin\Extensions\ScriptExtensions\" folder. When you start TC 8, it will install the extension automatically.

Comment: Thank you Alex, works on all computers and TestComplete versions now.